# How can I change this code to show WHY an insert failed? PHP, MySQLi, Prepared Statements

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm stuck on this problem and all error examples are using $stmt->error or something which I don't understand.  I write in procedural style not OOP.  My insert fails so I'm curious to debug it please...

```
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_USER_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(DB_CONNECT_ERROR);
    if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query)) die('SEL:mysqli_prepare');
    call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($stmt, 'sssssssssssssssssssssbsssss')), $idb);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)) {
            // Failed to insert
    } else {
            // Success
            }
```

My insert fails...  how can I see what the reason was?  Please and thank you in advance!  I'm also just learning prepared statements so if I did something wrong please advise...  The code makes it down to the // FAILED TO INSERT line and when checking cpanel the query did fail (there was nothing in the DB).

If you want to write your own example using the style of programming I used above and show me how to check if an insert failed that's cool too.  Once I see how you do yours I can change my code.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mysqli_stmt_error()` and `mysqli_stmt_errno()` to retrieve the error information:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

printf("Error #%d: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt), mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
```

### Note

I would recommend you to use

```
if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 0)
```

instead of relying on the ugly autocast feature of PHP

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
```

Comment: Thank you!   I was trying to use

$aaaa = mysqli_error($stmt);
die('!1!' . $aaaa);

and it wasnt working.   Didn't know about that mysqli_stmt_error!   Much appreciated!  I tried it, tested it and it told me my problem!  Thx!

Comment: Thank you I'll change my code!  == 0 or === 0 would be better?   Also the error I got was !1!No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement!1!   Is that line above correct?

call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($stmt, 'sssssssssssssssssssssbsssss')), $param);

I've checked $param and it matches perfectly with the 'ssss etc' string.  A partial dump of $param shows...

array(27) { [0]=> string(7) "PerryCS" [1]=> string(15) "email@msn.com" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) ""

Comment: THIS MATCHES TOO... $query = "INSERT INTO pcsuser (username, email, companyname, fname, lname, streetnum, streetname1, streetname2, unitapt, city, prov, pcode, "
   .  "country, hphone, wphone, wphoneext, cphone, fphone, contacthours, persistent_login, referid, comments, "
   . "pw1, pw2, pwordh, created_on, pk) VALUES ( ";
    
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $ni; $i++) {
   $query .= '?';
   if ($i < $ni) $query .= ", "; // dont append a ", " to last one
  }
  $query .= ")"; // finish off the $query

Comment: I've printed out the $query string and the $param string and they match (they go together properly).   Does the @ in email or the "" in some of the fields cause a problem?

Comment: Start with a simple INSERT statement and a dummy table that has only one column. If this works properly, continue with your complex query. When you have problems with your code, always reduce it to the basics and check if this works...

Answer (score -1):

If you echo the stmt, and try it directly in SQL, that's probably your easiest method.

To try in SQL, either use the command line if you can, or download phpmyadmin, really easy to install, and run the query in there.